# How to convert a readline variable to float in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a php variable I use to read user input in command line ("terminal"):

```
$x = readline("Type something: ");
```

I tried converting it to float:

```
$x = (float) readline("Type something: ");
```

But it did not work.

I searched about converting "user input/buffered input/input" to float/string/int in php, but I did not find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$x = (float)readline("Type something: "); var_dump($x);` should show float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `readline` is string. To convert a string to float you can use the php function `floatval($val)`. 
Here the link to the documentation of the function: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: I managed to do it by using the code below (I added a function to replace each comma with a period; this way, the user can type either "12,34" or "12.34" and it will "read" both as "12.34".  
`$number = floatval(str_replace(',','.',readline("Digite um numero: ")));`